# How do I show the Excel Save Changes Dialog

Tags: c#, excel

I am handling an OnWorkbookBeforeClose event and need to prompt the user to save changes.  There is plenty on how to disable the Save Changes Dialog, but nothing on how to show it...

(I need to tidy some things up.  If do so then get Excel to put this box up and the user presses cancel, there is no event that the user has not saved the workbook and it is still open and active).

Since there are no DialogButtons for a standard Dialog for SaveDontSaveCancel (closest is YesNoCancel) is there any way of showing this Save Changes Dialog?

(To be clear I am not interested in the Save or SaveAs dialogs, only the 'Save Changes' dialog which prompts: 'Do you want to save the changes to Book1.xks?  and has 3 buttons: Save, Don't Save, Cancel)

The XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogSaveWorkbook simply shows the Save dialog prompting for a file name (implying the user has already chosen 'Save').

Alternatively if there is an event raised after a workbook is closed then this would allow me to do what I need.

I would rather present the user with the correct Excel Dialog so don't really want to roll my own.

Comment: The 3 buttons that I remember are `Save`, `Don't Save`, and `Cancel`. I don't remember a dialog box which shows `Save, Save As, Cancel` in one box?

Comment: Indeed - well spotted, q edited.

Comment: Could you please post solution ? @GalleySlave

Answer (score 0):

You might set the `Saved` property of the workbook to `False` in the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event.  This would force Excel to display the Save/Don't Save/Cancel dialog @Siddharth mentioned after the event returns.  If the user chooses Cancel, the workbook will remain open.  Is that what you want?

Comment: No, I have to determine whether the user has pressed cancel before teh end of BeforeClose - if you set Saved to false, then the dialog is shown after the BeforeClose event, so I have no idea whether the workbook is closed or still open.